# Find specific string in every directory and run a command

Tags: bash, find, exec

I want to find a specific string in each directory and then run command X.

```
dir1 = contains a file with string "test"  = run command X
dir2 = X
dir3 = X
dir4 = contains a file with string "test" = run command X
```

I suppose there is a better way of doing this.

```
find . -type f -exec grep -rn -H "test" {} \; -execdir X {} \;
```

Comment: Does that work?  If not, what is the problem?  `find` is great for things like that, and you avoided the classic inefficient `for` or `while` loops some people do.  It if works, move on.

Comment: Hi! It works fine with commands like "ls" and "htop" and such, but not with ansible. So it probably doesn't fit for my use-case. I will try a for loop!

Thanks anyway..

Comment: Make sure you check the difference between modules command and shell in ansible.